# Why EventLog writes info into other log (MyNewLog instead of MyApp)?

Tags: c#, .net-core

C#, .NET Core 3.1, Windows 10 x64.

I want to use Windows Event Viewer via C#. For example I want to write the records into the Log. I use code from Microsoft manual:

```
using System.Diagnostics; // NuGet: System.Diagnostics.EventLog

namespace ConsoleAppThreading {
    class Program {

        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var source = "MySource";
            var logName = "MyNewLog";
            if (!EventLog.SourceExists(source)) {
                EventLog.CreateEventSource(source, logName);
                return;
            }
            EventLog myLog = new EventLog();
            myLog.Source = source;
            myLog.WriteEntry("Writing to event log.");
        }
    }
}
```

I ran this code twice. It works fine:

[image]

But if I change the `source` and `logName` values then I get unexpected behaviour:

```
using System.Diagnostics; // NuGet: System.Diagnostics.EventLog

namespace ConsoleAppThreading {
    class Program {

        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var source = "Bushman"; // Changed
            var logName = "MyApp"; // Changed
            if (!EventLog.SourceExists(source)) {
                EventLog.CreateEventSource(source, logName);
                return;
            }
            EventLog myLog = new EventLog();
            myLog.Source = source;
            myLog.WriteEntry("Writing to event log 3."); // Changed
        }
    }
}
```

I ran this code twice too. The result:

[image]

and

[image]

The log record was written into other journal (`MyNewLog` instead of `MyApp`). Why does it happen?

Comment: What does `return;` do?

Comment: @mjwills exit from application.

Comment: @mjwills original is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventlog.sourceexists?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: I guess, you should run the app twice, first when create a source and next time to write an event

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski, I know and I did it. My IDE works with admin permissions.

Comment: But when the event source does not exist, you create it and return without writing anything into it?

Comment: @OguzOzgul yes.

Comment: MyNewLog is probably already there in the first case. The source code you've provided returns without writing anything. If you delete both sources (appNames) and try the first one, it will exit without writing anything either.

Comment: @OguzOzgul I launched each code twice for getting the result I posted here.

Comment: Did you by any chance run the code with a Source of Bushman and a LogName of MyNewLog at anytime when you were testing?  If so, you may need to reboot as per the documentation "If a source has already been mapped to a log and you remap it to a new log, you must restart the computer for the changes to take effect."

Comment: @Tintow you are right. The reboot solved the problem. Where did you read it? Give me the link, please.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventlog.source?view=netframework-4.8  right at the bottom of the page

Comment: and the Core 3.1 link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventlog.source?view=netcore-3.1  It says the same thing.

Comment: @Tintow you can post your answer and I will mark it as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you by any chance run the code with a Source of 'Bushman' and a LogName of 'MyNewLog' at anytime when you were testing?

If so, you may need to reboot as per the documentation "If a source has already been mapped to a log and you remap it to a new log, you must restart the computer for the changes to take effect."

Link for core documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.eventlog.source?view=netcore-3.1